# Почему после перезагрузки eel выключается?

Tags: javascript, python, eel

Я запускаю код

python

```
import eel

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


@eel.expose
def get():
    settings = {
    'ff':'1',
    'vvv':'2',
    'eee':'3',
    'ddd':'4',
    'qqq':'5',
    }
    return settings





@eel.expose
def test_link(content,format):
    print('TEST')
    print(content)
    print('TEST')

eel.init('web')

eel.start("test.html", size=(700,700))
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
        
        <script src="eel.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        
        <script src="three/examples/js/libs/draco/draco_encoder.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="module">
        window.onload = function() {
        alert('Страница загружена');
    };
    
    
        async function run_eel(text,format){
        let res = await eel.test_link(text,format)();
    }
    
    
    let set = await eel.get()();
    
    
    alert('Страница загружен2а');

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

и он вырубается после одно или нескольких перезагрузок страницы
Могу ли я это как то исправить потому-что каждый раз запускать заново очень раздражает.

Я просто перезагружаю страницу и код вырубается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "он вырубается" что это означает? вылетает с ошибкой? с какой именно?

Comment: @CrazyElf в консоле никакой ошибки нет просто сам завершает работу. И после браузер говорит что не нашел страницу так как eel откючен.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script type='text/javascript' src="/eel.js"></script>
```

вы должны прописать этот код в head каждой страницы, которую открываете в eel. Сам долго парился с этой проблемой, в моём случае на одной из 3 страниц js вообще не нужен, поэтому я забыл прописать этот обязательный код.

Также вам необходимо подключить какой-либо js файл к странице, я не знаю почему, но без этого eel не работает. Файл может быть даже пустым.